# How can i export object to render a list of items in NextJs?

Tags: next.js

I have a form in a page and send that data to my API and store it a json file inside an object i want to export that object to render with a map function all my elements.

add.js:

```
import React from 'react'
import Layout from '@/components/Layout'
import styles from '@/styles/AddEvent.module.css'

export default function AddEventPage() {

  const submitHanlder = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const formData = {
      title: e.target.title.value,
      description: e.target.description.value
    }

    fetch('/api/events', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(formData)
    });
    console.log(formData)
  }



  return (
    <Layout title='Add New Event'>
        <h1>Add Event</h1>
        <div className={styles.container}>
          <form className={styles.form} action="" onSubmit={submitHanlder}>
            <label className={styles.label}  >Title</label>
            <input type="text" name="title" />
            <label className={styles.label} >Description</label>
            <input type="text" name="description"/>
            <label className={styles.label}htmlFor="">Date</label>
            <input type="date" />
            <button type='submit' >Submit</button>
          </form>
        </div>
    </Layout>
  )
}
```

events.js:

```
const handler = async (req , res) => {

    if(req.method === 'POST'){
        await fetch('http://localhost:3001/events', {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            method: 'POST',
            body: req.body
        })
        return res.status(201).json({ message: 'evento agregado' });
    }
    return res.status(400).json({ error: 'no se pudo agregar el evento' });
}

export default handler;
```

This is my db.json: where i store the events i add with my form.

```
{
  "events": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "Recital coldplay",
      "description": "Recital de coldplay en River"
    },
    {
      "title": "Recital metalica",
      "description": "Recital de metalica en velez",
      "id": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

How can i export this object above to render all my events in my front end?

This is what i tried:

index.js:

```
import React from 'react'
import Layout from '@/components/Layout'
import events from '../../db.json'

export default function EventsPage() {
  return (
    <Layout>
        <h1>My Events</h1>
        <div>
          {events.map((event) => {
            return <h1>{event.title}</h1>
          })}
        </div>
    </Layout>
  )
}
```

But i get this error: `TypeError: _db_json__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.map is not a function`

Comment: you can do something like this events.events.map(...). events is object and by . you will access the key which is events

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
import events from '../../db.json'
```

Should be:

```
import { events } from '../../db.json'
```